# Printer friendly web pages question

Tags: php, css

How do I make printer friendly web page using css and php that strips out style attributes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printer friendly should be handled purely with [a print media stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

You should avoid having style attributes in the first place. If you, for some reason, can't eliminate them then you can override them in the CSS with the sledgehammer of [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) (unless they use !important themselves).

Comment: +1 - this is the most maintainable and standard solution.  One exception where a totally separate version of the page could be useful is if you have paginated articles, where users might want to print all pages of a given article at once.  But in this case all that's needed is a "View All" version of the page with no pagination (and no other difference from "regular" version), combined with a print media stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

From google:

http://www.googobits.com/articles/640-printerfriendly-web-pages-made-easy.html